# java-to-java transformation using XSLT

Tags: java, xslt

I would like to create a method in a webservice that can recieve an object of a Java Class that has been created with JAXB and generate an object of another Java Class (created with JAXB as well) using an XSL file that defines the relation between the XML files that I have used with JAXB.

Any help?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please read the help on asking a question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Have you tried using the XSLT Transformer?

Comment: Hi Priyesh, yes, I have considered it. But I have only found example and guides to do it from an XML file or to an XML file but not from one instance of a Java Class to a new instance of another Java Class. Any ideaS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track by looking at the `javax.xml.transform` APIs.  A [`Transformer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) takes its input from an object that implements `Source` and sends its output to an object that implements `Result`, and there are [`JAXBSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/util/JAXBSource.html) and [`JAXBResult`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/util/JAXBResult.html) classes that will support the use case you're after

```
MySourceJaxbClass sourceObject = // ...
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
JAXBContext context = // however you need to create your context
Source src = new JAXBSource(context, sourceObject);
JAXBResult res = new JAXBResult(context);
transformer.transform(src, res);

MyTargetJaxbClass resultObject = (MyTargetJaxbClass)res.getResult();
```

Of course you don't necessarily have to use the same `JAXBContext` for both the source and the result - if they're unrelated class hierarchies it might make more sense to use a separate context for each.